# bash remove duplicate string from list

Tags: string, bash, grep

I want to delete duplicate strings from a String. Example:

```
A="Dog Cat Horse Dog Dog Cat"
```

The string A should look like this:

```
A="Dog Cat Horse"
```

How can I write a Shell script for that?

Comment: Check this link : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802734/sorting-and-removing-duplicate-words-in-a-line

Comment: @heemayl: the question you claim is a duplicate is about _sorting and removing duplicates._ This question here is not about _sorting_, only about removing duplicates…

Comment: @anubhava: the question you claim is a duplicate is about _sorting and removing duplicates._ This question here is not about _sorting_, only about removing duplicates…

Answer (score 10):

You could use this,

```
echo "a a b b c c" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

Comment: this reverses the order though.

Answer (score 7):

If order is not important, you can use an associative array:

```
declare -A uniq
for k in $A ; do uniq[$k]=1 ; done
echo ${!uniq[@]}
```

Comment: Is there a specific order in which the keys/indices are listed in case of associative arrays?

Comment: Note that this may fail if the original string contains glob characters. Can be “fixed” with `set -f`.

Answer (score 1):

1. (Safely) split the string on blanks, creating an array with each word:<sup>†</sup>

   ```
   read -r -d '' -a words < <(printf '%s\0' "$A")
   ```
2. Loop on the fields of the array, storing the words into an associative array; if the word was already seen, ignore it

   ```
   declare -A Aseen
   Aunique=()
   for w in "${words[@]}"; do
       [[ ${Aseen[$w]} ]] && continue
       Aunique+=( "$w" )
       Aseen[$w]=x
   done
   ```
3. You can print the `Aunique` array to standard output:

   ```
   printf '%s\n' "${Aunique[@]}"
   ```

   which yields:

   ```
   Dog
   Cat
   Horse
   ```

   or create a new string with it

   ```
   Anew="${Aunique[*]}"
   printf '%s\n' "$Anew"
   ```

   which yields:

   ```
   Dog Cat Horse
   ```

   or join the array with a separator, e.g., with the character `,`:<sup>‡</sup>

   ```
   IFS=, eval 'Asep="${Aunique[*]}"'
   printf '%s\n' "${Asep[@]}"
   ```

   which yields:

   ```
   Dog,Cat,Horse
   ```

All these use Bash≥4 features. If you're stuck on older Bash versions, there are workarounds but it won't be as safe and nice and easy…

**Note.** This method will not sort the string: the words remain in the original order, only with the duplicates removed.

---

<sup>†</sup>This is the canonical (and safe!) way to split a string on space characters (or, more generally on the characters contained in the special variable `IFS`, which has default value *space*-*tab*-*newline*). Don't use horrors like `words=( $A )`: it's subject to filename expansion (globbing). Another method widely encountered is `read -r -a words <<< "$A"`; this is fine (i.e., safe), but will not handle newlines in `A`.

<sup>‡</sup>The use of `eval` here is 100% safe (because of the single quotes); it's actually the canonical way to join the elements of an array in Bash (or to join the positional parameters in POSIX shells).

Comment: Is there a specific order in which the keys/indices are listed in case of associative arrays?

Comment: @anishane: the order is governed by the hash keys (an obscure cryptographical order). But in the case of this answer, the associative array is only used to remember the words that have already been encountered, not to build the final string (the order in which the words appear in `Aunique` is that of the original string).

Comment: Yes, got that... Just wanted to know, if the order was easily predictable in code. Then we could have used a simpler mechanism, similar to @choroba's answer....

Answer (score 1):

With gawk:

```
 awk -v RS="[ \n]" -v ORS=" " '!($0 in a){print;a[$0]}' <(echo $A)
```