# How To Remove Duplicate Words In Single Line When Piping Multiple Lines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, xargs

Right now, I am piping some lines through the command `xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs` (which I found here: [Sorting and removing duplicate words in a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802734/sorting-and-removing-duplicate-words-in-a-line)).

But, my problem is that when piping multiple lines, it puts all the lines together. How can I pipe through:

```
My first example line for example
My second example line for example
My third example line for example
```

And get:

```
My first example line for
My second example line for
My third example line for
```

Since I'm running a lot of pipes before this, and it will be running within a loop, I would prefer if you know any simple solutions without creating a new loop and reading line by line. I just want it to work for one line at a time so I can just put it right into the loop. Thanks for the consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{delete seen; c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!seen[$i]++) printf "%s%s", (++c>1?OFS:""), $i; print ""}' file
My first example line for
My second example line for
My third example line for
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simpler `awk` program, but without preserving the order (which neither your pipeline does, so I'm assuming that's not your requirement):

```
$ awk '{delete a; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; for(w in a) printf w" ";print ""}' lines 
first line My for example 
line My for second example 
line My third for example
```